# php mysql INSERT INTO column if exist

Tags: php, mysql

in a php file that use this line of code to insert some text in the table TABONE

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `TABONE` VALUES ('$q1', '$q2', '$q3',  '$q4',  '$q5')") ;
```

the code work fine because "**we receive 5 variables and this table contain 5 columns**"

but sometimes **we receive 5 variables for a table that contain only 3 columns and in this case we just want to insert the first 3 variables ('$q1', '$q2', '$q3')in the 3 columns**.

in this case

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `TABONE` VALUES ('$q1', '$q2', '$q3',  '$q4',  '$q5')") ;
```

doesn't work - How to correct this.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). *Edit*: You should really be explicitly specifying which column which value belongs to. Relying on current column ordering is dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html):

> - If you are not running in strict SQL mode, any column not explicitly given a value is set to its default (explicit or implicit) value. For example, if you specify a column list that does not name all the columns in the table, unnamed columns are set to their default values. Default value assignment is described in [Section 11.5, “Data Type Default Values”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html). See also [Section 1.8.6.2, “Constraints on Invalid Data”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/constraint-invalid-data.html).
>
>   If you want an [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statement to generate an error unless you explicitly specify values for all columns that do not have a default value, you should use strict mode. See [Section 5.1.6, “Server SQL Modes”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html).
> - Use the keyword `DEFAULT` to set a column explicitly to its default value. This makes it easier to write [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statements that assign values to all but a few columns, because it enables you to avoid writing an incomplete `VALUES` list that does not include a value for each column in the table. Otherwise, you would have to write out the list of column names corresponding to each value in the `VALUES` list.
>
>   You can also use [`DEFAULT(col_name)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default) as a more general form that can be used in expressions to produce a given column's default value.

Therefore, you can:

1. name the columns and omit those for which you want default values:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO TABONE (colA, colB, colC) VALUES ('$q1', '$q2', '$q3')
   ```

   Or, if you prefer the `SET` syntax:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO TABONE SET colA='$q1', colB='$q2', colC='$q3'
   ```
2. explicitly set the other columns to their default values with the `DEFAULT` keyword:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO TABONE VALUES ('$q1', '$q2', '$q3', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
   ```